# Javascript pointer to function

Tags: javascript

Javascript is def not my main programming language I for practice I wanted to do something simple, at least i thought ;)

This is my code:

```
function Log () {}

Log.format = function (func, facility, text) {
    func("hellow");
};

Log.debug = function(facility, text) {
    Log.format(console.warn);
};
```

When I call Log.debug("we", "deb"); I get a Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the browser, `console` methods can only be called in the context of `console`. Try `Log.format(console.warn.bind(console));`

Comment: If possible could you elaborate why this is so?

Comment: As to the question *why*: I don't know. It's different in Firefox.

Comment: @MouNtant: `console` is basically an extension by the browser, it's not a standard JS feature. So the *why* question can only be answered by the people working on providing this extension.